# How decode html string to readeble form using perl

Tags: perl

I'm new in perl, and if i use the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::YouTube::Info::Simple;

my $id = 'aPLnXzjWMZE';
my $yt = WWW::YouTube::Info::Simple->new($id);

my $info = $yt->get_info();
print $info->{title};
```

and as result I become: Tornyosi+m%C5%B1sor

How can decode (or what module should be using) for readable string **Tornyosi műsor** ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[URI::Encode](http://p3rl.org/URI::Encode) or [URI::Escape](http://p3rl.org/URI::Escape) will handle the `%` encoded characters. The `+` to space you'll have to do yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use URI::Encode;

my $encoder = 'URI::Encode'->new;
( my $s = 'Tornyosi+m%C5%B1sor' ) =~ s/\+/ /g;
$s = $encoder->decode($s);
print $s, "\n";
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use URI::Escape;

( my $s = 'Tornyosi+m%C5%B1sor' ) =~ s/\+/ /g;
my $s = uri_unescape($s);
print $s, "\n";
```

You might need to decode the strings if you want to output to an io layer with encoding. See [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode).

Comment: Thank you very match. :)

Comment: @vatay, Fixed a bug.